# Rotational motion problem. Pulsar with period $T=0.033$ sec. increasing at a rate of $1.26\times10^{-5}$ sec/yr. Find the angular acceleration

Tags: rotational-dynamics

I understand that $\omega=\frac{2\pi}{T}$ so we can derive $\frac{d\omega}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{2\pi}{T}\right)=-\frac{2\pi}{T^{2}}\frac{dT}{dt}=-\frac{2\pi}{T^{2}} k$, with $k=$ rate.

However, the proposed solution directly substituted $T=0.033$ to find the acceleration and to my understanding given a linear incremental, T should be something like $T(t)=T_0 + kt$ with $T_0=0.033$ and $k$ the linear increment per second, resulting in $\alpha(t)$ variable.

Is it because of the way of simplifying the problem, or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you asking why we can directly substitute $T$ into the given equation for $\frac{\mathrm{d}\omega}{\mathrm{d}t}$?

Comment: @DanDan0101, yes. Why is it $\alpha=-\frac{2\pi}{(0.033)^{2}} k$ instead of $\alpha=\frac{-2\pi}{(0.033+kt)^{2}} k$?

Comment: it is because we are solving for the instantaneous angular acceleration.